# Teamcity docker image build cannot create build directory Permission denied

Tags: docker, permissions, teamcity

I have a docker image being built from a teamcity (TC) job. The Dockerfile is shown below. Essentially it cannot run as root, so a new user is created as projects. The code base is in /home/projects and the build output get created under /home/projects/build and the user is projects creating the build output. The build works when I build using manual docker commands. The same setup fails building from TC complaining cannot create the /home/projects/build directory - permission denied.

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04.5
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# extra metadata
LABEL version="1.0"
LABEL description="First image with Dockerfile."

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
dialog \
autoconf \
automake \
libtool \
...
sudo \
git
```

As seen above (commented out lines), I have tried a couple of different ways of creating user projects. I dont quite understood who needs permissions here to create /home/projects/build ...? Is it TC user that needs permissions or root or the user project. Probably not project because all that works in the non TC build. Any thoughts on how the permissions work on a docker container in a Teamcity build job?

```
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] Creating dockerbuild_supernova_run ... 
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] Creating dockerbuild_supernova_run ... done
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] make/gdb.mk:13: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/projects/build/platform/gdb-7.0.1/.source'
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] make/cross-gdb.mk:12: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/projects/build/platform/gdb-7.0.1/.source'
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] make/u-boot.mk:31: warning: overriding commands for target `/Makefile'
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] make/at91boot.mk:23: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Makefile'
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] mkdir -p /home/projects/build/platform
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/projects/build': Permission denied
[15:48:33]  [Step 1/1] make: *** [/home/projects/build/platform] Error 1
[15:48:34]  [Step 1/1] 2
[15:48:34]  [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 2
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
somename:
   image: imagename:1.0
   user: $UID:$GID
   build: .
   volumes:
       - ../:/home/somehome
       - ../:/home/whateverotherdirectories
   working_dir: /home/somehome
   stdin_open: true # docker run -i
   tty: true        # docker run -t
```

build-container.sh

```
export UID=$(id -u)
export GID=$(id -g)

docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml run --rm supernova bash -c "make"
```

enter code here

Comment: Can you share more information about your build?  It seems you are running `make`.  Are you building this image and then executing `make` commands inside it?  Can you share details about how the docker container is run, especially the `docker run` command?  It does not seem that anything is failing to _build a docker image_.

Comment: From a script:
buildimage.sh:
     docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml run --rm myimage bash -c "make"

docker-compose:
version: "3.8"
services:
  myimage:
    image: myimage:1.0
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ../:/home/projects
      - ../toolchain/:/home/toolchain
    working_dir: /home/projects
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t

This is everything I do.

Comment: Sorry, couldnt keep format in the above message. I use a simple script from where I run the docker compose and dockerfile

Comment: Np, you should edit your question to include that info.  Looks like you are mounting your current directory into /home/projects/ in your container, so the permissions and uid/gid will be from the host machine.  For this to work you need the uid of the user in your container to match the uid of the owner of wherever you are executing this script from on the host machine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I am mounting the pulled repo (current directory) onto /home/projects. The build works with the set permissions in Dockerfile on my host machine/in the docker container. However when I try building with the same setup on Teamcity, I get the permission denied error. I am trying out all your suggestions but I have not succeeded so far.

Comment: The uid on `/home/projects/` on the teamcity server must not be 1000.  Check the permissions and uid/gid on the server (`ls -al /home/projects/`).

Comment: Resolved: By dynamically getting UID/GID from a script and passing it to docker-compose file, I was able to get past the permissions error. Thanks for the tip. Edited code above to show what I did.